# How do I run bulma on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, npm, yarnpkg, bulma

I can't run `bulma` on Heroku and `npm` is not a Heroku command.

What should I type to do `npm install bulma` on Heroku? Do I need to use yarn?

`brew install yarn`, `yarn add bulma` doesn't work on Heroku either.

Here is the error I'm seeing:

> Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass.

Comment: What language is your main application written in? Heroku uses language-specific buildpacks and if your application isn't in JavaScript `npm` and `yarn` won't be available out of the box.

Comment: Ruby on rails, I can run on my mac but not on heroku

Answer (score 4):

Don't install Bulma yourself, and certainly don't try to install `yarn` via Homebrew.

Heroku's ephemeral filesystem will prevent it from working properly, interactive commands run on temporary one-off dynos that only exist as long as your session runs, and `brew` is mostly a macOS package manager (though a Linux version does technically exist).

Heroku will build your application for you as long as you tell it how.

1. Make sure to include a `package.json` and `package.lock` or `yarn.lock` that includes the JavaScript libraries you need
2. Tell Heroku [which buildpacks to use](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) for your application:

   ```
   $ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
   $ heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
   ```

   Make sure the Ruby buildpack is last:

   ```
   $ heroku buildpacks
   === your-app Buildpack
   1. heroku/nodejs
   2. heroku/ruby
   ```
3. Deploy your code

Heroku will run the Node.js buildpack first and install JavaScript packages from your lock file, then run the Ruby buildpack and install your gems.